# Reciprocal over a summation

Tags: summation, fractions

Is this statement true? Can we take reciprocal over a summation? $$\frac 1{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{(n+1)^3}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)^3$$

Comment: The sum on the right obviously diverges

Comment: Are you actually asking us if $\dfrac1{a+b}=\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b$ ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not true. By simple inspection, the sum in the denominator on the left side is a finite number, so the left side is finite. But the right side is apparently infinite.

Answer (score 0):

No.  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^3}=\zeta(3)-1$, so it's reciprocal is $\frac{1}{\zeta(3)-1}$  which is a finite number.
The term on the right is obviously divergent.

For reference, $\zeta(3)\approx 1.20205690315959...$ and is called Apery's constant.